# ContentSecurityPolicyViolation

Tags: lift, content-security-policy

I'm trying to implement a basic chat application with Lift 3 and lift-ng (Angular). Mostly, this is working. However, I am getting this warning in my (server side) log:

> [qtp1721931908-24] WARN
>   net.liftweb.http.ContentSecurityPolicyViolation - Got a content
>   security violation report we couldn't interpret:
>   'Full({"csp-report":{"document-uri":"http://localhost:8081/","referrer":"","violated-directive":"script-src
>   'unsafe-eval'
>   'self'","effective-directive":"script-src","original-policy":"default-src
>   'self'; img-src *; script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'self'; style-src 'self'
>   'unsafe-inline'; report-uri
>   /lift/content-security-policy-report","blocked-uri":"inline","status-code":200}})'.

What I want to know is *how to track down what is causing that violation*? I am pretty unclear what part of the code or binding might be surfacing that, or how to narrow it down without having to painstakingly comment out every single part of the codebase.

I can easily get rid of the violation by setting up this `SecurityRule` in my `Boot.scala`:

```
LiftRules.securityRules = () => {
  SecurityRules(content = Some(ContentSecurityPolicy(
    scriptSources = List(ContentSourceRestriction.Self,
      ContentSourceRestriction.UnsafeInline,
      ContentSourceRestriction.UnsafeEval)
  )))
}
```

However, I'd like to avoid using the unsafe inlining/eval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the developer console of your browser, it may contain a link to the inline code. e.g.

[image: CSP Error in Firefox Console]

When I clicked on "hash:2:0" it took me to the html source of the page, line 2, character 0 which is exactly where the offending code was:

[image: inline script]

One thing to note is that a lot of plugins (e.g. lastpass) generate this alert. Be sure to disable all plugins while testing.